# Why are red blood cells preferred to study the structure of plasma membrane?

Tags: cell-biology, lab-techniques, cell-membrane, red-blood-cell, plasma-membrane

If we wanted to study the structure of a plasma membrane, why are red blood cells a more attractive cell type to work with than other cell types such as liver cells or kidney cells?

Comment: Did you try to find an explanation anywhere else before asking here? Why do **you** think that might be the best way to harvest cell membranes?

Comment: What is unsatisfactory about the explanation?

Comment: I would actually say they are all pretty terrible, unless you wanted something specific to look at in a cell type. The correct answer would be liposomes in a biophysical context, endosomes in a biological context, nanodiscs in a structural biology context (other answers of of course acceptable)! Whole cells are a nightmare unless you need some cell-specific information. Without knowing the explanation given, this question is unanswerable.

Comment: @James - I don't know if I could disagree with you more. The answer is really obvious.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Perhaps my comment was a little facetious, but I am trying to say that the question is missing a key point; some sort of testable hypothesis. The question remains unclear. If I want to study the PM structure relative to other bilayers structures, I don't need to work with specific cell types, rather _many_ cell types ([Sharpe _et al_ 2010](http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S0092867410006124)). If I want to compare the PM to other cell types, I need other cell types. If I wanted a crystal structure of how a particular protein sits in the PM, I need a nano-disc etc.

Comment: @anongoodnurse If I want to answer `"If we wanted to study the structure of a plasma membrane, which of the following would be the best cell to do so?"` My knee-jerk response is `"It depends on what you want to know"` regardless if there is an easy-to-handle option (and still, there are _easier_ to handle options than RBCs).

Comment: @James - I understood that (believe it or not), and generally agree with your argument. However, the question was basic and non-specific; rbcs are basically just cell membranes surrounding an easily separable 'cytoplasm'. Lyse the cells, wash, and violà. Which cells would be easier? (I'm sincerely curious.)

Comment: @anongoodnurse I see your point and you've convinced me that the question has value. I've removed the homework-y-ness of the question and limited it to specifically whole cells making my comments redundant :P Until OP comes back with some research, the question still stands at risk of closure for lack of effort.

Comment: @James - Fair enough, and I've already VTC.

Comment: @James what are examples of "easier to handle options than RBCs"?

Comment: @AlwaysConfused Liposomes and endosomes are typically less messy when it comes to results analysis for many experiments, particularly for molecular biology. Whilst the RBCs are relatively simple cells, they still contain a lot of proteins that may interfere with your interpretation of the results. To reiterate, this depends on what you are wanting to know specifically, which the question is currently missing. After my edit, these options aren't viable since they're not complete cells, but rather bilayer models.

Comment: @James Thank you. Artificial-liposomes would best from viewpoint of purity and simplicity. But we don't have to 'prepare' any RBC with [technologies](https://avantilipids.com/tech-support/liposome-preparation/) like sonication etc. Also I assume (no experience) liposomes and similar naturally available structures like [chylomicrons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chylomicron) would be more difficult to handle due to small size. Also to isolate phagosomes we have to rupture the cell membrane, and separation task would be more difficult than RBC. so when high accuracy not reqd, RBC is easier.

Comment: Thanks for the help everyone. No, there is no explanation. I'm a junior in high school and came across this question in a biology practice book. That's all it stated, which cell would be the best for studying the structure of a plasma membrane? Only thing we have in our course is the fluid mosaic model and lipid bilayer so I guess it refers to that. The solution said RBC but didn't give any explanation, so i asked it here as I am curious to know why.

Comment: @AlwaysConfused I've only been involved in the biophysics end of molecular biology so I'm quite narrow minded about methods. RBCs are simple to a cell biologist, but those same cells might be too complex for a molecular biologist!

Comment: @James Me too never did experiments with rbc (except only viewing them under microscope) and did only very few experiments on cell-membranes in college and university botany courses. I've put the comments and answer from common sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Human RBCs are relatively simple in structure compared to the other cells in question; they contain no cell organelles (**so far I knew; please correct me if there is any new theory**) and therefore contain only one membrane.

RBCs do not have significant amount of extracellular matrix making them very easy to work only with the cell membrane. RBCs float in a fluidy medium (blood-plasma), so easy to collect, distribute in containers, keep into various solution. no need of maceration. [Human RBCs are very uniform in shape and size](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC1304195/), and do not divide. That makes it useful for various experiments like demonstrating plasmolysis and deplasmolysis as well as quantitative experiments on membrane biomolecules.

One classic example is [Edwin Gorter and F. Grendel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Membrane_models#Gorter_and_Grendel.27s_membrane_theory_.281925.29) that first showed that cell membrane is bilayer; that is upon observation on RBC. They took known number of RBC, denatured the membrane, extracted the lipids and spread that as a lipid monolayer on water-air interface. They found that the monolayer is twice bigger than total surface area of taken RBC ! `*`

> Source:  `*` The Cell/ Cooper/ 4th Edition/ASM-Press and Sinauer publication.

---

However this is not a reference-based answer, but these are the features more than enough to make me so lazy that I would choose only RBC and flyaway from any-other option.

Comment: I guess this explains it to me anyway.